# Taking an error (qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display) while trying to use kdbg, when connected through ssh

Tags: qt, ssh, archlinux, kde-plasma, kdbg

When I'm connected through ssh, and tried to run kdbg I took this problem:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

I use KDE Plasma (X11), and Arch Linux.

I tried to reinstall qt6-base package, install qt5-base package, also found a lot of the same questions in other forums, but nothing helped to me

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as I understand, this concerned not only kdbg, but any program with a graphical interface.
Second I found explanations on Arch wiki in the article about OpenSSH https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/OpenSSH#X11_forwarding

So all i had to do, to solve this problem is add `-X` to the command. So instead of
`ssh user@server-address`
I wrote `ssh -X user@server-address`

Comment: But! After some time, this problem appears again, message the same instead of this line: `qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:10.0`, it solves when I reconnect ssh, but I don't understand the cause of this problem.